# How do you tell whether preg_replace() didn't match or matched from start?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Both conditions returns false, how can you distinguish them?

Can it be done without using the third parameter?

Comment: Can you provide some example code.

Are you sure you're talking about preg_replace()?  The third parameter is the subject which is required.

The PHP manual says that preg_replace() doesn't return false either, but null on error, the original subject on no matches, or the modified subject if matches are found.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can put some sample code here, but you can look into the fifth argument: `$count`, which is the number of replacements done.

Answer (score 0):

You may be talking about [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) which returns false if it doesn't match anything or 0 if the 'needle' matches the very start of the 'haystack'. These are both 'falsey' values, so you need to explicitly check them with a triple equals operator:

```
if (strpos($haystack, $needle) === false) {
    // $needle NOT found in $haystack.
} else {
    // $needle was found in $haystack.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

preg_replace can have multiple references, so if you made you first reference something like `/^(.){min,max}` where min/max is your minimum/maxium number of characters you're trying to match in the beginning, that match would be \\1 and the next set of parens would be \\2 and so on.

Without more information, its hard to tell if this or other solutions will work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp var containing search string.

After replace check if new string == temp var.

If equivalent return false else return true.